# Spring Boot properties вне jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, properties

Я разрабатываю программу с помощью Spring Boot и я столкнулся с такой проблемой.
У меня есть application.properties файл в папке resources, но мне также нужен файл external.properties вне jar файла для конфигурации таких полей как имя, пароль и тд. Я хочу чтоб external.properties был рядом с jar файлом и внутри папки resources для тестирования во время разработки. Я пытался создать такйо файл конфигурации:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:" + SpringConfiguration.EXTERNALIZED_PROPERTIES)
@PropertySource(value = "file:./" + 
SpringConfiguration.EXTERNALIZED_PROPERTIES, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class SpringConfiguration {
   static final String EXTERNALIZED_PROPERTIES = "external.properties";
}
```

Но считывается все равно файл внутри папки resources. Как сделать так чтоб считывался файл вне jar файла?

Comment: когда у вас уже есть jar, то вам нужно либо external.properties указать в classpath, либо через некий параметр передать путь к нуму

Comment: Где-то читал, что должно быть достаточно просто положить файл application.properties в ту же папку, что и jar-ник. И он имеет приоритет над тем, который в resources. Так не пробовали?

Comment: А использовать переменные окружения для передачи параметров приложению не хотите ?

Comment: Удалите из resources в jar этот файл и уложите вместе с либами. Вроде должно помочь

Comment: @gooamoko да, спасибо, это решило проблему.